# How to listen to Composer's autoloading?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a way to somehow listen to Composer's autoloading process and run my own callback when a file is found for a class?

**Use case**: I have an old project with its own autoloading system that keeps a cache of class/file map. I would like to start using vendor libraries and Composer's autoloading but at the same time I want to be able to add those classes and their respective files into that old caching system.

Comment: [This](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) might help.